# Attempting to generate HTML in vanilla JS using document.write, then access the tags using .getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

My goal is to do something like this:
https://djduncan585.github.io/noob-code-generation-problem/index2.html

I was able to accomplish this by hard-coding HTML into the index2.html file itself, then executing a JavaScript routine hard-coded using `<script>` toward the bottom of the page that uses document.getElementById to access each of the individual nodes and change their content with .innerHTML; this substitutes a single randomly generate digit between 0 and 9 in any of 56 randomly selected nodes on the page forming a 14 x 4 grid using `<div>` and `<span>` tags.

Trouble is when I try to do 2 things:
1) Dynamically generate the page using document.write with two nested loops (I know this works properly because I copied and pasted the results of this code into index2.html to get it to function), and
2) Access the results using the same routine that I used in index2.html to change the digits, but encapsulated in an external JS document accessed in the HTML document.
When I try to run this with the routines kept in a separate document (see the same address as above but subtracting the "2" from index2.html. StackExchange won't let me post more than 2 links with my current reputation level), the page renders as expected, but the looping function called later to change the contents of the nodes doesn't work.

What am I doing here that's causing the page to not animate?
(See also https://github.com/djduncan585/noob-code-generation-problem.)

```js
   window.onload = () => { let changeDigits = setInterval(changeADigit(), 1000); };
```

```html
<script>
function initialize() {
  for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    document.write('<div class="row">\n');
    for (let col = 0; col < 14; col++) {
      document.write(
        '<span class="digit" id="digit' +
          (row * 14 + col) +
          '">' +
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +
          "</span>\n"
      );
    }
    document.write("</div>\n");
  }
}

function changeADigit() {
  document.getElementById(
    "digit" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 56)
  ).innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and code HERE: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - I made one for you. Please add whatever necessary.

Comment: Remove the () from changeADigit() in the interval - now it only runs ONCE on the first invocation

Comment: just add this setInterval(changeADigit,0.1); to your initialize function instead of calling it in window.onload

Comment: @mplungjan: Nailed it; thank you! You get the cookie.